# Compare string within numerical ranges - Java

Tags: java, string

I need help with this string format: "08/13/2015 10:03:50"

I would like to compare the time within a range of 2 min. I get regex to a point but would not know how to go about this when the time is in string format and the cross over to another hour, (Ex. 10:59:30 would lap over to 11:01:30 not 10:61:30).

Code would be something like

```
string1 = "08/13/2015 10:03:50";
string2 = "08/13/2015 10:05:50, 08/13/2015 10:55:50, 08/13/2015 10:15:50, 
            08/13/2015 10:14:50, 08/13/2015 10:25:50, 08/13/2015 10:55:50";

if(string2.contains("string1(with plus or minus 2 of string1 min)"){
   //Pass
}
```

Code I am using to grab the date

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String timeOfUpdate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(timeOfUpdate);
```

Comment: This is not a job for a regex.

Comment: Just parse it as a Date, not as a String

Comment: What would it be then? I thought of hamming distance but that too is not what I would need.

Comment: I updated the question with the code I am using to grab the date.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am comparing that date to a string of dates, so I am going through a list of multiple dates checking if there is one within 2min of the current date. So I would not be able to use that. I need to do it as a string.

Comment: ok, so split string2 by ',' into an array, parse each element as a Date, and compare each Date element to the Date that you wish (perhaps there is a more efficient approach)

Comment: Nice idea. Wonder how long it would take to run that...

Comment: @MCD23 I hope you dont' need a Calendar to count the runtime :)

Comment: @vefthym lol nope, just patience. The file can have up to 1000 dates logged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the `Strings` as `Date` like suggested in the comments, then retrieve the timestamps of both `Date` objects through the [getTime() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--). Subtract these two numbers from one another. This get's you the chronological distance of these times in *milliseconds*, which you can compare to your criteria converted to milliseconds.

**Update** regarding the date list addendum: To evaluate a String containing a list of dates, you have to split the string along the list separator into an array of strings by using [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Then, you can parse each sub string into a Date object and retrieve the timestamp of each as per the #getTime() method mentioned in the first paragraph. Collect these timestamps into a list.

This list can be searched for entries within the expected range, for example using the [Stream API's filter function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) (Java 8 and newer). Here's a short [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/streams.html#stream-filter) about that function.

Comment: Would this work on a string with a list of multiple dates? I updated the code to show what I mean by that. I have a large number of dates I would like to check through all and determine if any have a date within 2 min of the searched date.

Comment: @MCD23 I updated my answer to include an algorithm regarding your string of list of dates edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the below steps:

1. Convert String1 into Date Object and apply getTime() method, store the      result in some variable
2. Convert String2 into a array of Strings by using split on comma
3. Run a loop on results retrieved in step#2, inside loop

   - Convert each value fetched into Date Object
   - Call getTime on date object converted
   - Subtract this number with the one fetched in Step#1
   - Now you will get the difference in milliseconds(1 min = 60000 miliseconds)
   - if the difference is either greater than -120000 or less than 120000 miliseconds than break the loop and set the flag to true.

   Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Ugh so much work. Was really hoping it was as easy as searching with a regexed expression. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date.getTime()` for getting date in milliseconds since 1970 and split your date string arrays :

```
int offsetMinutes = 2;

String string1 = "08/13/2015 10:03:50, 08/14/2015 10:05:50, 08/14/2015 10:05:50";
String string2 = "08/13/2015 10:05:49, 08/14/2015 10:05:50, 08/15/2015 10:05:50";

String[] string1Array = string1.split(",");
String[] string2Array = string2.split(",");

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

for (int j = 0 ; j< string1Array.length;j++)
{
    Date date1 = format.parse(string1Array[j].trim());

    for (int i = 0; i < string2Array.length; i++) {
        Date date2 = format.parse(string2Array[i].trim());
        if (date1.getTime() >= (date2.getTime() + offsetMinutes * 60 * 1000) || date1.getTime() <= (date2.getTime() - offsetMinutes * 60 * 1000)) {
            //Here we are
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give it a try and report back if it worked or not. Thanks a ton!

Comment: What would i need to change if string 2 was a list of multiple dates? see updated question above.

Comment: I would accept this as the answer, but it's not quite what I need which is not your fault. I guess I didn't give enough info out. I would not be able to use the delimiter "," because it is not even in the strings, I just used that as an example. In reality, each date also has an unpredictable length of text pended on. So say its a sale of an iPhone and iPad. It would be something like string1 = " iPhone sold using cash 8/13/2015 10:05:30 iPad sold using card 8/13/2015 10:06:30".